jQuery filter results with checkboxes
I have the below code for a simple checkbox filter. It works well if all conditions are met with the checkboxes, i.e. Monday or Tuesday are checked. But checking both Monday and Tuesday gives no results. I would like  it to show results that have a Monday or a Tuesday but can't adapt what I have.


$('form#filter').on('change', function() {

  var filterList = [];

  $("form#filter .checkDays input:checked").each(function() {
    var dataDays = $(this).val();
    filterList.push(dataDays);
  });

  $("form#filter .checkTime input:checked").each(function() {
    var dataTime = $(this).val();
    filterList.push(dataTime);
  });

  if (filterList.length == 0) {
    jQuery('.card').removeClass('is-hidden');
    jQuery('.card').fadeIn();

  } else {

    jQuery('.card').filter(function() {
      const isVisible = ['data-combined'].some(attr => {
        const attrValue = jQuery(this).attr(attr);
        if (!attrValue) {
          return;
        }
        const offerings = attrValue.split(',');
        return filterList.every(offering => offerings.indexOf(offering) > -1);
      });

      if (isVisible) {
        jQuery(this).fadeIn('slow');
      } else {
        jQuery(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }

});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="filter">
  <h3>Filter</h3>
  <h4>Day</h4>
  <div class="checkDays"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="Monday" /> Monday</div>
  <div class="checkDays"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="Tuesday" /> Tuesday</div>
  <div class="checkDays"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="Wednesday" /> Wednesday</div>
  <div class="checkDays"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="Thursday" /> Thursday</div>
  <div class="checkDays"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="Friday" /> Friday</div>
  <div class="checkDays"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="Saturday" /> Saturday</div>
  <div class="checkDays"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="Sunday" /> Sunday</div>
  <h4>Time</h4>
  <div class="checkTime"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="AM" /> AM</div>
  <div class="checkTime"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="PM" /> PM</div>
  <div class="checkTime"><input class="" type="checkbox" value="ALL DAY" /> ALL DAY</div>
</form>

<div class="noresults"></div>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'session', 'posts_per_page' => 50)); while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<div class="card" data-combined="<?php the_field('AM/PM');?>,<?php $field = get_field_object('day'); $days = $field['value']; if($days): foreach( $days as $day ): echo ',' . $field['choices'][$day]; endforeach; endif; ?>">
</div>




Can you replace the PHP code with sample HTML, so the snippet will have something to filter?

.filter() should be .each(). You use .filter() when you're using the result, it returns a new collection of all the elements that matched the filter condition.

Change filterList.every to filterList.some. every requires that all checkboxes match, some requires that at least one checkbox matches.
